# Public file system path problem

Tags: files

The "Public file system path" setting in admin/config/media/file-system was always reflecting the directory name of my multi site directory.

I don't know what caused the problem, but it doesn't automatically set the right dir anymore and I need to manually change it when I create a site.

Does anybody have an idea of what might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by reverting to a older version of the database. I haven't been able to trace the real cause of the problem.

It had something to do with "Backup and Migrate" module, because that was the only real change between the versions.